# Closed form of $\int_0^T W(t) \sin(t) \mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I want to evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{T} W(t) \sin(t)   \mathrm{d} t$$
where $W(t)$ is a Wiener process.

Context: I want to simulate paths of Karhunen Loeve expansion and compare them to a given path of brownian motion. To do so I need to evaluate the given integral. I've tried with Ito formula and got
$$ \frac{1}{6}W^3(t)\cdot \sin(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t} W^2(s) \cdot \sin(s)\mathrm{d}W(s)-\frac{1}{6} \int_{0}^{t}W^3(s)\cdot \cos(s)\mathrm{d}s 
+\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t}W(s)\cdot \sin(s)\mathrm{d}s$$
which doesn't seem to make it any easier.
My alternative is to solve it numerical but I'd prefer a closed form.

$\textbf{Edit}$
For more context see [Pathwise Limit of Karhunen-Loeve Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4528709/1093356)

Answer (score 3):

You can partially integrate to obtain

$$
\int_0^T \sin(t)W_t dt = \int_0^T \cos(t)dW_t - \cos(T)W_T
$$

This is a centered Gaussian random variable. It's variance is given by

$$
\operatorname{Var}\left(\int_0^T \cos(t)dW_t\right) +
2 \operatorname{Cov}\left(\int_0^T \cos(t)dW_t, -\cos(T)W_T\right) +
\operatorname{Var}\left(\cos(T)W_T\right)
=: A+2B+C
$$

The terms above can be calculated explicitly:

$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= \int_0^T \cos^2(t)dt = \frac 12 (T + \sin(T)\cos(T))\\
B &= -\cos(T) \int_0^T \cos(t) dt = -\cos(T)\sin(T)\\
C &= T \cos^2(T)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your expense. Maybe I expressed myself poorly indeed I know the distribution of the integral. I left some constants out for this question, altogether its distribution is $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. I want the value of the integral dependent on the path $W(t)$. As far as I can see, with this method I get the integral but no information about the corresponding path.